# Specifying default bokeh toolbar behaviour in theme

Tags: python, themes, bokeh

Is it possible to write a theme for bokeh such that, e.g. the drag tool and the zoom wheel tool are active by default? I know how to set these active by accessing the properties of the figure, but I'd like to put all the default stuff that I want to use for all my plots in the theme.

I've looked through the documentation for themes and the documentation for the toolbar but haven't come up with a solution. The only thing I was able to find is how to deactivate a tool by default, e.g.

```
{
    'attrs': {
        'Toolbar': {
            'active_scroll': None
        }
     }
}
```

Is this possible via theme or am I out of luck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible because all the `active_*` properties of `Toolbar` must be set either to `"auto"` (which sounds like something you *don't* want) or to the desired tool instance. And you cannot put an instance into JSON.

You could maybe write a theme JSON preprocessor that would accept a toolbar and that would set the relevant tool instances. But even if that's possible, it has at least two downsides:

1. You will have to set the theme after the toolbar is created and populated
2. You cannot share the theme between documents or apply the theme to a document with multiple toolbars

Comment: Hmm, right - it's called JSON but it's not actually a JSON data. And that's what I mention in the point 1 in my answer - you have to set the theme not as `Document(theme=...)` but as `doc.theme = Theme(...)`. This way, the instances of all tools should be already available.

Comment: Yeah I just noticed that you talk about setting the theme after creating the toolbar. Yeah maybe this could work.